# Standalone GORM (based on Grails 2.0)

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

This topic has come up at various times over the years, the most recent solution apparently being the pet clinic sample app:
https://github.com/grails-samples/petclinic

That was built against Grails 1.3.5, however.

With Grails 2.0 GA days away, it would be really nice to get standalone GORM running with the 2.0 enhancements.

Grails user list is silent on the topic of standalone GORM (core devels likely scrambling to get 2.0 out the door)

Anyway, if anyone has details feel free to share...

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bugreport for standalone gorm in grails 2.0.1, however workaround is included. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9383 attachment and description.
Project contains test successfully saving/loading domain entity even with persistence events.

Comment: I am really happy to no longer be using Grails ;-), but nice work on getting some flavor of standalone GORM in place (core devs have had that request on their plate for quite some time...)